# Reference Request: Nicole Oresme history

Tags: reference-request, exponentiation, math-history, mathematicians

It says on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicole_Oresme#Mathematics) that

> [Nicole Oresme] also worked on fractional powers, and the notion of probability over infinite sequences, ideas which would not be further developed for the next three and five centuries, respectively.

Does anyone know of a translated work or summary (preferably English) of Oresme's work on **fractional powers** specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some material (partial translation and commentary) into the "old classic" :

> Marshall Clagett, [Science of Mechanics in the Middle Ages](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0299019004) (1959)

and of course the full translation into :

> Marshall Clagett (editor), [Nicole Oresme and the Medieval Geometry of Qualities and Motions; a treatise on the uniformity and difformity of intensities known as Tractatus de configurationibus qualitatum et motuum](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005CJY1WM) (1968).

For Oresme's generalization of traditional theory of proportions, including (in modern terms) fractional exponents, see :

> Edward Grant (editor), [Nicole Oresme De Proportionibus Proportionum and Ad Pauca Respicientes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0299040003) (1966).